# Impossible to change the height of a container in Recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, height, containers, parent-child

I have had a big trouble since several hours;

I have a recyclerview with several elements in each item. For one of them (lv_container), I can decrease its height but not increase it.

See the screenshot: [image]

the xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dashboard_part_medical_file_locked_title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/row_dashboard_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_part_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dossier_medical" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lv_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dashboard_part_image"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dashboard_part_image"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dashboard_part_image"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sup" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/sup"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_part_medical_file_inside" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code of the viewholder

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = pContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lvContainerParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lvContainer.getLayoutParams();
lvContainerParams.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lvContainerParams.height = (int) (40 * metrics.density + 20 * metrics.density);
lvContainer.setLayoutParams(lvContainerParams);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams mainContainerParams = mainContainer.getLayoutParams();
mainContainerParams.height = (int) (lvContainerParams.height + 20 * metrics.density);
mainContainer.setLayoutParams(mainContainerParams);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) (mainContainerParams.height + 50 * metrics.density);
itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

When I change the height of lvContainer (the white container), the height of mainContainer is well modified (as you can see with the blue container), but the  white container always remains fixed. However, in debug, heights are well calculated.
I tried to call `lvContainer.invalidate()` and/or `lvContainer.requestLayout()`, but nothing changed.

What's the error? Why the height of item and mainContainer can be easily modified, but not this of lvContainer?

I need your help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dashboard_part_image"
```

Comment: A so simple solution, but the good one. I was too much focused on params.height that I don't look at the layout carefully. Thanks so much